# Ruby on Rails: Where should I put the third party css/js files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded some css/js files online and would like to reuse it on my site. The folder structure is like this:

```
assets
   cs
   js
   <some extra folders like images, etc>
```

Since they are 3rd party library and I don't want to put it in my asset folder of my project. I am wondering where I can put it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In rails 3.2, 3rd party javascripts files are put in the folder

```
vendor/assets/javascripts
```

and CSS files are put in the folder

```
vendor/assets/css
```

Javascripts files are required in application.js as

```
//= require filename
```

Css files are required in application.css as

```
*= require filename
```

**NOTE :-** Both files will not contain their extension as .js or .css when required in the application.css and application.js file

Answer (score 1):

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

for css, and

```
vendor/assets/javascripts
```

for js